# How to optimize number regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

## Issue

A string should be tested whether it contains numbers with optional characters between the digits. I'll use the terms *number* meaning a series of digits (e.g. `123`) and *digit* meaning an element of a number (e.g. `0`, `1`, `2`).

Example strings the regex should test and detect the number `012345`:

```
abc 012345 def
abc 0.1.2.3.4.5 def
abc 0-1 2a3x4,,,5 def
```

### Characteristics

- a) The numbers are known, i.e. it should not match *any* number but specific numbers.
- b) The symbols between digits are unknown and of unknown lengths; though in practice, the length won't exceed 10 in 99% of cases.
- c) The strings to test are < 100 characters in 99% of cases.

The code run in JavaScript Node.js:

```js
// For each regex
for (const regex of regexes) {
  if (new RegExp(regex, 'iu').test(text)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The most simple (and most inefficient) regex requires a significant compute time:

```js
const regexes = [
  '0.*1.*2.*3.*4.*5',
  '1.*1.*2.*2.*3.*3'
];
```

Is there any potential optimization, either in the regex or in the JS code?

---

## Performance

Execution time comparison from suggestions in comments and answers below, in order from fastest to slowest:

1. remove non-number chars with `str.replace(/\D/g, '')` and then use the regex `012345` is the fastest; it's not a pure regex optimization, but as I said, the optimization can include the JavaScript code (thanks @anubhava)
2. use negated character classes `0\D*1\D*2\D*3\D*4\D*5` is only ~4% slower than (1) and doesn't require any additional JS code, so it's the best pure regex optimization (thanks @WiktorStribiżew)
3. with real word data, both the greedy `1.*2.*3.*4.*5` and range limited `1.{0,10}2.{0,10}3.{0,10}4.{0,10}5` variants are ~50% - 90% slower than (1)

Comment: Won't it be simpler to remove all non-digits and compare with number like this: `str.replace(/\D+/g, '') == '012345'`

Comment: I'm not sure if limiting the regexes is actually better. I just ran a [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/w2l8vdqrc0/2) and it seems like the first one is faster. Though I've not tested it thoroughly, just did a quick JSBench.

Comment: Do number order matters here?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski "The numbers are known, i.e. it should not match any number but specific numbers." Note the difference between a "number" and a "digit".

Comment: @anubhava Your suggestion turns out to be the fastest one, if you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors and OP has confirmed in comment above that *Your suggestion turns out to be the fastest one*.

Seeing all different combinations of non-digit characters present between the digits, it would be much easier to do a `.replace` and remove all non-digits before comparison like this:

```bash
str.replace(/\D+/g, '') == '012345'
```

Here, pattern `/\D+/` matches one or more non-digits and we remove it with empty string to ensure only digits are left in original string for simple comparison.

Comment: Turns out that `\D+` is actually slightly (<0.5%) faster than `\D`.

Comment: Indeed it will be faster as it will reduce `.replace` invocation when there are more than 1 contiguous non-digit chars.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `\D*` between the digits:

```js
const regexes = [
  '0\D*1\D*2\D*3\D*4\D*5',
  '1\D*1\D*2\D*2\D*3\D*3'
]
```

The `\D*` pattern matches any zero or more non-digit chars.

Comment: I was hoping you'd answer ;-) I'm trying to wrap my head around this. Is this behaving like a lazy operator? So instead of backtracking, does this compare forward, or why is this faster?

Comment: @Manuel It is better than a lazy operator as the greedily quantified negated character classes match whole chunks of text much quicker, without any backtracking.

Comment: While I will actually use your answer in practice (since it doesn't require any JS code modification and is only ~3% slower), I will accept @anubhava's answer as it's the fastest one in the profiling test.

Comment: I think there's a flaw in this answer: the negated char should be `[^\d]*`. Otherwise, the regex for number `123` will match the string `1223`, which is a different number. I just did a benchmark, and `[^\d]*` is ~45% slower than the fastest solution, which is almost as slow as the original greedy `.*` operator which is ~53% slower than the fastest solution.

Comment: You mean `[^\d]*1`? Because `1` is already in `\d` I guess, so `[^\d1]` is the same as `[^\d]`?

Comment: This won't match for example `0-12345`. Between two digits there can be any alpha character but not a numeric character.

Comment: @Manuel Ok, it was not clear what kind of chars you want to allow. Use `\D*` in between digits.

Comment: That works, and `\D*` is ~50% faster than `.*`, how come?

Comment: @Manuel Because  `\D` is a shorthand character class that matches any non-digit char. It is equivalent of `[^\d]`, so basically the negated character class I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I assumed the negation is what made this non-greedy and therefore it was faster. But here its just replacing `.` "any char" with `\D` any "non-numeric char". So this doesn't have the backtracking behavior?

Comment: In case of `1\D*2` there is no backtracking as `\D` does not match `1` and `2`. There is no way to re-match the pattern in any other way.